# Cumulative histogram with log-log scale

Tags: plotting, histograms

How to do a cumulative histogram on *Mathematica* on a log-log scale? This question is pretty straightforward, but a search didn't help me at all. Keep in mind that all I have is a list of n numbers
Thanks for the help

Comment: `s = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100];BarChart@Log@Accumulate@BinCounts[s, .1]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With some random numbers

```
rNumbers = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100]
```

you can get a cumulative histogram with a log-log scale using

```
Histogram[rNumbers, "Log", {"Log", "CumulativeCount"}]
```

> [image: cumulativeLogLogHistogram]

Comment: +1 now I feel silly for doing it the hard way..

Comment: Thanks! But somehow I can't make it work with a log scale on the counts. If I just do
Histogram[numbers,"Log","CumulativeCount"] it works, but as soon as I add the "Log" it gives me an error message:
The height specification {Log,CumulativeCount} is not one of the named height functions or a function that can be used to compute the heights for each bin.

Comment: @bernie you have to use quotation marks: `{"Log", "CumulativeCount"}`

Answer (score 1):

```
 data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2, .1], 100];
 ListPlot[ Transpose[{Mean /@ Partition[#[[1]], 2, 1],
     Accumulate@#[[2]]}] &@HistogramList[ data ] ,
     Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}]
```

[image]

```
 BarChart[ Accumulate@#[[2]] &@ HistogramList[ data ] ]
```

[image]

Edit :

missed the loglog part earlier, properly we need to cook up logarithmic bins:
( or go read the `Histogram` docs and see that this is built in.. )

```
 data = RandomVariate[WeibullDistribution[  10, 1 ], 100000];
 logbins = N@Exp[FindDivisions[  Log[ Sort[data][[{1, -1}]] ] , 10 ]]
 BarChart[ Log@Accumulate@BinCounts[ data ,  {logbins}] , 
     ChartLabels -> Mean /@ Partition[logbins, 2, 1]]
```

[image]